# ¿Como instalar basemap en Python?

Tags: python

Cuando intento correr un script de python que contenga "from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap", me muestra:

```
File "mapVLF.py", line 10, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

¿Como lo puedo descargar desde la terminal?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás usando anaconda, simplemente cuando te encuentres en tu entorno, en la terminal ejecuta:

`conda install -c anaconda basemap`

Si quieres instalarlo con pip puedes instalarlo desde el repositorio oficial de Github mediante la terminal:

```
pip install --user https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/v1.1.0.zip
```